# Xamarin.Forms dependencies and Android compiling sdk version

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, nuget

I'm trying to add some xamarin android related nuget packages into my project.

When I see https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/3.1.0.583944

> Dependencies
>
> - MonoAndroid 7.1
> - Tizen 4.0
> - UAP 10.0

Does `MonoAndroid 7.1` mean that I can only use Android 7.1 as my compiling version? What if I use Android 8 which is MonoAndroid 8.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Using MonoAndroid 8.0 should be fine. Consider it more of a minimum required version number. Also, a word to the wise, make sure that all projects in the solution are using the same Xamarin Forms version. It will save you headaches.